# How to convert C program to JavaScript equivalent?

Tags: javascript, c

Given

[Base independent sequencer for A217626](http://oeis.org/w/images/e/e6/A217626.c)

```c
/*
 * ########################################## 
 * # Base independent sequencer for A217626 #
 * ##########################################
 * 
 * This program is free software.
 * Written by R. J. Cano (remy at ula.ve, Or reemmmyyyy at gmail.com)
 * On Jan 9 2014, for educational purposes and released under 
 * the terms of the General Public License 3.0 (GNU-GPL 3.0);
 * 
 * There is NO warranty not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
 * 
 * Note: For a large set of terms (>10!-1) the present program might be prone to data type overflows.
 * 
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long _base= 10;
long _showOffset= 1;
/** Standard output field width. An aid for comparisons using MD5 checksums. **/
long _normWidth= 13; 
/** Set this to 0 for print everything in a single line. **/
long _onePerLine= 1;
/** 0 for the vector representation, 1 for the integer representation **/
long _objectToShow= 1;

long permute(long*, long*, long);
long vec2polyEval(long*, long, long);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  long v1[100],v2[100],v3[100],u[100],n,k,l,offset=0;
  _showOffset*= _onePerLine;
  /* The size of the output (n!-1 items) is no longer read from the standard input. 
     scanf("%li",&n); -- Does stop silently, therefore it is avoided. */
  n= strtol(argv[1], NULL, _base); /* Direct conversion from the command line parameter(s) */
  for(k=0; k<100; k++) {
    v1[k]= (k<n)*(k);
    v2[k]= v1[k];
    v3[k]= 0;
  }
  while(permute(v2,u,n)) {
    for(k=0;k<n-1;k++) {
      v3[k+1]=0;
      for(l=k+1;l<n;l++) {
    v3[k+1]+=(u[l]-v2[l]);
      }
    }
    if (_showOffset) printf("%li ", ++offset);
    if (!_onePerLine) printf(",");
    if (!_objectToShow) {
      for(k=0;k+n<_normWidth;k++) { printf(",0"); }
      for(k=0;k<n;k++) { printf(",%li",v3[k]); }
      printf(";");
    } else {
      printf("%li", vec2polyEval(v3,_base,n));
    }
    if (_onePerLine) printf("\n");
  }
  if (!_onePerLine) printf("\n");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

long permute(long *data, long *previous, long Size) {
  long tau, rho=Size-1, phi=Size-1;
  for (tau=0;tau<Size;tau++) previous[tau]= data[tau];
  while((rho > 0)&&(data[rho]<= data[rho-1])) rho--;
  rho--;
  if(rho<0) return 0;
  while((phi > rho)&&(data[phi]<=data[rho])) phi--;
  tau= data[rho];
  data[rho]= data[phi];
  data[phi]= tau;
  Size--;
  rho++;
  while(Size>rho) {
    tau= data[Size];
    data[Size]= data[rho];
    data[rho]= tau;
    Size--;
    rho++;
  }
  return 1;
}

long vec2polyEval(long* v, long B, long m) {
  long ans=0, pow=1, k;
  for(k=m-1;k>=0;k--) {
    ans+= v[k]*pow;
    pow*= B;
  }
  return ans;
}
```

What have tried so far, which resulted in apparent infinite loop at jsfiddle

```js
var _base = 10;
var _showOffset = 1;
/** Standard output field width. An aid for comparisons using MD5 checksums. **/
var _normWidth = 13;
/** Set this to 0 for print everything in a single line. **/
var _onePerLine = 1;
/** 0 for the vector representation, 1 for the integer representation **/
var _objectToShow = 1;

// long permute(long*, long*, long);
// long vec2polyEval(long*, long, long);

function main( /*int argc, char **/ argv /*[]*/ ) {
  var v1 = Array(100),
    v2 = Array(100),
    v3 = Array(100),
    u = Array(100),
    n, k, l, offset = 0;
  _showOffset *= _onePerLine;
  /* The size of the output (n!-1 items) is no longer read from the standard input. 
     scanf("%li",&n); -- Does stop silently, therefore it is avoided. */
  n = parseInt(argv[1], _base); /* Direct conversion from the command line parameter(s) */
  for (k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
    v1[k] = (k < n) * (k);
    v2[k] = v1[k];
    v3[k] = 0;
  }
  while (permute(v2, u, n)) {
    for (k = 0; k < n - 1; k++) {
      v3[k + 1] = 0;
      for (l = k + 1; l < n; l++) {
        v3[k + 1] += (u[l] - v2[l]);
      }
    }
    if (_showOffset) console.log("%li ", ++offset);
    if (!_onePerLine) console.log(",");
    if (!_objectToShow) {
      for (k = 0; k + n < _normWidth; k++) {
        console.log(",0");
      }
      for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        console.log(",%li", v3[k]);
      }
      console.log(";");
    } else {
      printf("%li", vec2polyEval(v3, _base, n));
    }
    if (_onePerLine) console.log("\n");
  }
  if (!_onePerLine) console.log("\n");
  return "EXIT_SUCCESS";
}

function permute(data, previous, Size) {
  var tau, rho = Size - 1,
    phi = Size - 1;
  for (tau = 0; tau < Size; tau++) previous[tau] = data[tau];
  while ((rho > 0) && (data[rho] <= data[rho - 1])) rho--;
  rho--;
  if (rho < 0) return 0;
  while ((phi > rho) && (data[phi] <= data[rho])) phi--;
  tau = data[rho];
  data[rho] = data[phi];
  data[phi] = tau;
  Size--;
  rho++;
  while (Size > rho) {
    tau = data[Size];
    data[Size] = data[rho];
    data[rho] = tau;
    Size--;
    rho++;
  }
  return 1;
}

function vec2polyEval(v, B, m) {
  long ans = 0, pow = 1, k;
  for (k = m - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
    ans += v[k] * pow;
    pow *= B;
  }
  return ans;
}

main([1,2,3]);
```

Questions:

- Does `long v1[100],v2[100],v3[100],u[100]` assign `v1` as the value as an `Array` having `.length` `100`, or a `Number` having value `100`?
- Is [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) equivalent to [`parseInt()`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-parseint-string-radix)?
- What is purpose of `long permute(long*, long*, long)` and  `long vec2polyEval(long*, long, long)`?
- What is purpose of `int argc` at `main`, where `argc` does not appear to be used in function?
- How to convert the `c` code to `javascript`  equivalent?

Comment: In the JS, `argv[1]` should be `argv[0]`. C passes the path to the executable itself at index 0, that doesn't happen when you create an array like `[1,2,3]`. `argc` denoted the length of the `argv` array (like `argv.length` in JS) - and IMO the C code _should_ use it, because running it without any arguments invokes undefined behaviour AFAIK. It's also part of the `main` function signature if `argv` is present, so you can't really omit it here.

Comment: @Siguza Where should `argc` be used?

Comment: v1[100] creates an array of length 100

Comment: strtol is very similar to parseInt.
strtol converts a string (or an array of chars) and converts to an integer

Comment: @guest271314 One should test whether `argc` is greater or equal to `2` before attempting to access `argv[1]`.

Comment: int argc is the number of command line arguments passed to main, in other words it's the length of argv[]

Comment: Also note that `console.log` cannot really be taken as an equivalent to `printf`, since `printf` does not append a newline to the string given to it whereas `console.log` prints everything on a separate line.

Comment: Note, normally would invest greater time into trying to convert, for own edification, before asking Question; noting the bugs along the way. However, time is of the essence with as to current Question, as need to vet the pattern to adhere to a time-sensitive bond.

Comment: @Siguza No value is logged to `console` when `0` is set as index at `argv[0]` https://jsfiddle.net/t7612no0/ ?

Comment: If the current Question is "too broad" for stackoverflow.com, where to ask?

Comment: @guest271314 And that is consistent with calling your C program with an argument of `1`. I call `[status-bydesign]`.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes The Questions is limited to the bullet points. Is that not scope not limited enough? Did not post the code here without trying to convert the code first. What further needs to be limited in Question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Does `long v1[100],v2[100],v3[100],u[100]` assign `v1` as the value as an `Array` having `.length` `100`, or a `Number` having value `100`?

Array of length 100.

> - Is [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) equivalent to [`parseInt()`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-parseint-string-radix)?

Under normal conditions, yes.
Note that in your JS code you wouldn't need it though, since you're passing in actual integers rather than strings.

> - What is purpose of `int argc` at `main`, where `argc` does not appear to be used in function?

In C you're dealing with raw memory, so in order to not do something stupid, you need to know where your data ends (in this case `argv`).
And the C code *should* use `argc`, at least to check whether or not `argv[1]` even exists.
Running it without any arguments on my machine gives me a segmentation fault.

> - How to convert the `c` code to `javascript` equivalent?

First, replace all remaining type names by `var`, otherwise you'll get a syntax error.
Other than that, the only thing you need to take care of are the `printf`'s, which... you cannot just replace by `console.log` I'm afraid.
`printf` does not append a newline to its argument, whereas `console.log` prints everything on a separate line. Moreover, the first argument to `printf` can include format specifiers (`%...`) which get replaced by the additional arguments given to it, formatted in a given way.

I would solve this by changing the function to *return* the output rather than *directly printing* it. For that I'd create a `ret` value that is a string, and instead of using `printf`, you append to that string.
As for the format specifiers, if you have something like

```
printf(",%li",v3[k]);
```

then that means "append a comma and the value of `v3[k]` formatted as a long int (`%li`)". In JS, that would simply be:

```
ret += "," + v3[k];
```

Lastly, I would change the type of input. You don't need an `argv` array in JS when you're only passing a single value (also note that in C, `argv[0]` is the path of the program itself).

All that applied, I get:

```js
var _base = 10;
var _showOffset = 1;
/** Standard output field width. An aid for comparisons using MD5 checksums. **/
var _normWidth = 13;
/** Set this to 0 for print everything in a single line. **/
var _onePerLine = 1;
/** 0 for the vector representation, 1 for the integer representation **/
var _objectToShow = 1;
// long permute(long*, long*, long);
// long vec2polyEval(long*, long, long);
function main( /*int argc, char **/ arg /*[]*/ )
{
    var ret = "";
    var v1 = Array(100),
        v2 = Array(100),
        v3 = Array(100),
        u = Array(100),
        n, k, l, offset = 0;
    _showOffset *= _onePerLine;
    /* The size of the output (n!-1 items) is no longer read from the standard input. 
       scanf("%li",&n); -- Does stop silently, therefore it is avoided. */
    n = parseInt(arg, _base); /* Direct conversion from the command line parameter(s) */
    for(k = 0; k < 100; k++)
    {
        v1[k] = (k < n) * (k);
        v2[k] = v1[k];
        v3[k] = 0;
    }
    while(permute(v2, u, n))
    {
        for(k = 0; k < n - 1; k++)
        {
            v3[k + 1] = 0;
            for(l = k + 1; l < n; l++)
            {
                v3[k + 1] += (u[l] - v2[l]);
            }
        }
        if(_showOffset) ret += (++offset) + " ";
        if(!_onePerLine) ret += ",";
        if(!_objectToShow)
        {
            for(k = 0; k + n < _normWidth; k++)
            {
                ret += ",0";
            }
            for(k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                ret += "," + v3[k];
            }
            ret += ";";
        }
        else
        {
            ret += vec2polyEval(v3, _base, n);
        }
        if(_onePerLine) ret += "\n";
    }
    if(!_onePerLine) ret += "\n";
    return ret;
}

function permute(data, previous, Size)
{
    var tau, rho = Size - 1,
        phi = Size - 1;
    for(tau = 0; tau < Size; tau++) previous[tau] = data[tau];
    while((rho > 0) && (data[rho] <= data[rho - 1])) rho--;
    rho--;
    if(rho < 0) return 0;
    while((phi > rho) && (data[phi] <= data[rho])) phi--;
    tau = data[rho];
    data[rho] = data[phi];
    data[phi] = tau;
    Size--;
    rho++;
    while(Size > rho)
    {
        tau = data[Size];
        data[Size] = data[rho];
        data[rho] = tau;
        Size--;
        rho++;
    }
    return 1;
}

function vec2polyEval(v, B, m)
{
    var ans = 0,
        pow = 1,
        k;
    for(k = m - 1; k >= 0; k--)
    {
        ans += v[k] * pow;
        pow *= B;
    }
    return ans;
}

var ret = main('5');

// For demo:
document.body.innerText = ret;
document.body.style.whiteSpace = 'pre';
```

For the values I've tested it with, it gave me the same results as the C program.